# DataTypeException with Jooq newRecord and an enum

Tags: java, sql, enums, jooq

I have a simple object named `Group` which contains a `GroupType` enum.

```
public enum GroupType {
    PRIMARY,
    SECONDARY
}
```

I construct a new `Group` and save it

```
Group group = new Group();
group.setName(PRIMARY.name());
group.setType(PRIMARY);
Group g = save();
```

`save` starts out with

```
R record = (R) dsl.newRecord(Groups.GROUPS, group);
```

This line of code is throwing

```
  Caused by: org.jooq.exception.DataTypeException: Cannot convert from PRIMARY (class com.domain.entities.support.GroupType) to class com.domain.jooq.generated.enums.GroupType
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert$ConvertAll.fail(Convert.java:1113)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert$ConvertAll.from(Convert.java:1002)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert0(Convert.java:316)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert(Convert.java:308)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert(Convert.java:380)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.convert(DefaultDataType.java:698)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.setValue(Tools.java:1975)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractRecord.from(AbstractRecord.java:829)
```

How do enums work with `newRecord`?

Comment: What database are you using? Did you generate enum classes from your database?

Comment: Using Postgres 9.5. Yes, I have generated enum classes from the database. Essentially I end up with a `GroupType` enum as above, and then a Jooq genearted `GroupType` (same name, different package). I don't have anything special in my pom.xml where the config for generation is defined. Just some custom types for `java.time`. Is this the correct approach or is something needed for enums?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it:

```
Cannot convert from PRIMARY (class com.domain.entities.support.GroupType)
                          to class com.domain.jooq.generated.enums.GroupType
```

It appears that you're using two different types for your `GroupType` enum. jOOQ only understands the jOOQ-generated enum type (`com.domain.jooq.generated.enums.GroupType`), not your own one (`com.domain.entities.support.GroupType`).

If you really want to use your own enum type, you'll need to register a `Converter` on the `TYPE` column to convert between the two types.